# Write text over a circle using html and css

Tags: html, css

I'd like to write some text on a circle (I mean, the text will not be horizontal, but every letter will have a different orientation).
Is it possible using html and css?
Thanks you!

Comment: example? what have you tried? were not to make stuff but to fix stuff

Comment: you can use lettering.js .ref:http://css-tricks.com/set-text-on-a-circle/

Comment: do some googling, before you post on SO :)

Comment: see http://tympanus.net/Development/Arctext/

Comment: I can be done I think but wouldn't it be much simpler to make an image in photoshop and add it as an img tag, that way it's also cross browser compatible

Answer (score 3):

There isn't any super simple standardized way to set web type on a circle (or any kind of curve). But it can be done! We'll explore one way to do it here. But be forewarned, we're going to use some CSS3 and JavaScript and not give two hoots about older browsers that don't support some of the required tech. If you're interested in this for a real project, this kind of thing is probably still best served by and image with proper alt text, or proper feature detection which can flip out the image for this fancy technique in browsers that can handle it. ***Thanks to the css-tricks.com***

[DEMO](http://css-tricks.com/examples/TypeOnCircle/)

[DOWNLOAD FILES](http://css-tricks.com/examples/TypeOnCircle.zip)

[DOCUMENTATION](http://css-tricks.com/set-text-on-a-circle/)

**HTML**

```
<h1>
  <span class="char1">E</span>
  <span class="char2">s</span>
  <span class="char3">t</span>
  <span class="char4">a</span>
  <span class="char5">b</span>
  <!-- you get the idea -->
</h1>
```

CSS

```
h1 span {
  font: 26px Monaco, MonoSpace;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}

.char1 { transform: rotate(6deg); }
.char2 { transform: rotate(12deg); }
.char3 { transform: rotate(18deg); }
/* and so on */
```

**THERE IS A SUPER DEMO GIVE FROM THE** [HERE](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/simple_circle_text_example/)

Answer (score 1):

You can but you will end up having to do some major math to accomplish your goal. You will want to use the following CSS as a starting point.

```
.rotate {

/* Safari */
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);

 /* Firefox */
 -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);

  /* IE */
 -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);

 /* Opera */
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* Internet Explorer */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);

}
```

From css-tricks.com